# Disable plugins to make the app run faster

Tags: cordova

I'm working on a PhoneGap project.

I've seen in PhoneGap.plist that there are some options like "EnableAcceleration" or "EnableLocation" which can be YES or NO..

If we don't need those features, it's better to disable them to make the apps run faster.
But below we have the plugins list of PhoneGap..

Can I remove them? Would it cause any issue? Do we know which plugins is the heaviest?
Are there any other tips to make the application lower?

Answer (score 0):

Any plugins you don't need you can remove.
When you go through the list you'll be able to spot quite easily which plugins you do and which ones you don't use.
It will make your app a bit smaller and therefor maybe start up just a bit faster but don't expect the web app itself to run faster.
The browser remains a fairly slow element in the equation.

Using Phonegap 3 you'll automatically limit the amount of plugins that you're using so upgrading might be a good idea ;)